# Use of undeclared type 'GADUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, admob, native-ads

I am trying to make a demo of [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-ios/index.html#0) ads. While i follow this tutorial. **Getting this error Use of undeclared type 'GADUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate'.** I am using the latest version of GoogleMobileAds.framework.

AppDelegate

```
import Firebase

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511")

    return true
  }
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate
```

Comment: Show your code in AppDelegate.

Comment: @ElTomato check my updated question.

Comment: Just remove 'import Firebase' from ViewController.

Comment: Same error after remove 'import Firebase'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an older version(7.25.0) of Admob. The latest one is 7.29.0. When i have written **pod 'Firebase/AdMob'** in podfile at that time i got version 7.25.0. Then after i write **pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'** so i got 7.29.0 version of AdMob.